# How can i show shipping address and shipping method on virtual product too?

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, shipping-methods, shipping-address, virtual-products

How can i show shipping address and shipping methods on virtual products ?

If i am doing hide check of isVirtual in Magento/Catalog/Model/Product it will then treat like simple product.

I want to use virtual product till then place order .

Answer (score -1):

The concept of virtual product and difference from simple is a flag from `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType::isVirtual`. Virtual product  means the product doesn't need to ship and don't need to collect shipping address and shipping method. I think you need to review your logic or provide more details about what are you want to implement.